# Remove elements of ArrayList based on another ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have three arraylists. Two hold coordinates for points on a canvas (xCoord, yCoord). This is a dot to dot program. The third arraylist holds the code to calculate which dots can be removed from the canvas with the lowest "damage" or marring of the resultant picture. This is based on a simple algorithm, which returns a "critical value". Dots with smaller critical values mar the picture less than those with higher critical values.

My problem is removing n number of dots from the x and y arraylists based on the smallest critical value. I have the code for user input implemented already.

```
public void removeDots(int numberDesired){
    int i = 0;

    for (i =0; i<numberDesired; i++){

        xCoord.remove(critDots.get(i); //No idea, just trying random things. 
        yCoord.remove(critDots.get(i);

    }
}


   for (i = 0; i < xCoord.size()-1; i++) {
            critValue = Algorithm Calculations
            critDots.add(critValue);
        }
```

I've thought of using

```
Collections.sort(critDots)
```

to organize from least critical to most critical, but I'm unsure of how this will affect the order of my xCoord/yCoord.

Just some tips to help me get in the right direction would be appreciated. 
Also, xCoord, yCoord, and critDots are all arraylists.

Comment: `The third arraylist holds the code to calculate which dots can be removed from the canvas` by `dot` you mean pair of `x` and `y` co-ordinates which are to be removed?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Please provide a full [mcve] instead of explaining parts of the code. Question is for example : what kind of objects are you storing in those lists? As I guess: you are probably calling the remove(object) instead of remove(index) methods by mistake (or the other way round). That can happen because of automatic boxing of int values into Integer objects. Actually, that is most likely the case here.

Comment: And finally: don't use TWO lists to represent dots. Create a Dot class that contains two coordinates ; and then use ONE list of such Dot objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your x and y values in a separate `Dot` class:

```
class Dot {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    // hashValue and equals methods
}
```

Store the list of dots on the canvas in a list:

```
List<Dot> dots;
```

This is likely to be a much better model for you than storing x and y coordinates in separate lists. It is also better OO design as it will allow you to add attributes to the dots (e.g. colour) without having to change the model.

Use your 'damage' algorithm to get the dots causing the smallest damage:

```
List<Dot> toRemove = dots.stream()
    .sort(comparingInt(d -> calculateDamageForDot(d)))
    .limit(numberToRemove)
    .collect(toList());
```

If you're not familiar with streams then let me know in comments and I'll provide an old-style iteration that does the equivalent.

Then, finally, remove dots with the smallest damage:

```
dots.removeAll(toRemove);
```

Comment: Thank you, making a Dot class makes a lot of sense I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that by `dot` you mean pair of `x` and `y` co-ordinates, then you need both of them while removing them from `ArrayList`. Simply find pair of `x` and `y` co-ordinates and remove them.

Remember to remove both of them because you've to preserve order.

```
public void removeDots(int x, int y){
    //find that pair
    for(i=0; i<xCoord.size(); i++) {
        if(xCoord.get(i) == x && yCoord.get(i) == y) {
            xCoord.remove(i);
            yCoord.remove(i);
            break; //don't remove this break if there are duplicate co-ordinates in your lists.
        }
    }
}
```

Now simply call the above method and remove them:

```
...
removeDots(3, 5);
...
```

*However, it would be better to create a custom data type for your "dots" instead of managing two arraylists like this.*